# How can I SSH to remote server through VPN, running on a VM?

Tags: ssh, vpn, virtualization, port-forwarding

I have an Ubuntu VM that is connected to a VPN (using OpenConnect on Ubuntu), and I want to SSH from my OS X host to the VPN through Ubuntu:

```
(osx_host)  --ssh-->  (ubuntu_vm)  --ssh-->  (remote_server_on_vpn)
```

I've tried using [SSH port forwarding](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding) with the commands below to forward Ubuntu's port 9922 to the remote server's port 22 such that SSH'ing to Ubuntu's port 9922 would connect to the remote server, but I'm getting unexpected results.

#### Trial 1

```
osx_host$ ssh -R 9922:remote_server_on_vpn:22 ubuntu_vm
osx_host$ ssh localhost -p 9922
```

#### Trial 2

```
ubuntu_vm$ ssh -L 9922:remote_server_on_vpn:22 localhost
osx_host$ ssh ubuntu_vm -p 9922
```

But these only open a shell to Ubuntu and not the remote server.

#### Trial 3

```
ubuntu_vm$ ssh -D localhost:9922 remote_server_on_vpn
osx_host$ ssh ubuntu_vm -p 9922
```

but the connection to port 9922 times out. I've already verified that my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` contains `AllowTcpForwarding yes` and rebooted. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The command should be

```
osx_host$ ssh -fNL 9922:remote_server_on_vpn:22 ubuntu_vm
osx_host$ ssh localhost -p 9922
```

Remember to end existing connections.

Comment: This does not work

Comment: @superuser how? Connection refused? Timed out?

Comment: It results in the same behavior as Trials 1 and 2 (connects to `ubuntu_vm` rather than the remote server).